# Cancelling subscriptions for App and Play Store

Tags: google-play, app-store, in-app-subscription

We have an app for both IOS and Android and it will be ending soon.  We have quite a few users who have subscribed on a monthly or annual basis.  We will be offering them a deal with another vendor but need to cancel everyone subscription with this app so they don't get rebilled.  If we simply pull the apps from the stores will this also cancel their subscriptions or is there something else we need to do?

- Also is there an easy way to see how many active subscriptions we have for the app in the various categories?

Thanks in advance.

- S